# regex match zero and spaces

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm looking for a regex that captures all 0 values and spaces. Find any combinations like that:

1. 0000 0 0 0 000 000
2. 0 0 0 00000 00000
3. 00000000

I've tried using

```
[0\s]+$
```

but it doesn't work correctly. How should I rewrite my regular expression?
(I'm trying to figure out how to do it, but..( )

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: please add typical inputs and output, your input looks your output?

Comment: You can learn a lot about regexes on interactive sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) and [regexr.com](https://regexr.com).

Comment: In order to write a regex, you must know what types of strings it should match, think of *requirements*. What are yours?

Comment: I *think* you want to use `0+(\s+0+)*`, but without more details, I cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want zeroes and spaces you should use this,

```
[0 ]+
```

\s captures all white spaces which are spaces, tabs, new lines, carriage return. So just place 0 and space within square brackets

Comment: @Downvoter Please also tell what's wrong in my answer. OP wanted a regex that only matches zeroes and spaces and that should be the simplest possible regex for that

Comment: FWIW, I've also received a (at least to me) strange downvote on my answer. I've long since given up trying to figure out what causes these - sometimes, the anonymity of SO is more curse than blessing.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Exactly the same feeling here brother and it was little annoying initially but later when I noticed your answer (which was also correct) was downvoted too for no reason, I kind of guessed who else it can be other than third answer's author (Nikhil Sugandh). He didn't agree either with yours nor mine answer and downvoted both of us and went ahead and posted his own answer which was initially actually wrong to which he edited and ended up using my regex. May be he is still a novice and learning. Handling these situations could be further refinements for SOF.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this](http://rextester.com/FFOGN83174) :

```
with t(id,value) as
(
 select 1,'0000 0 0 0 000 000' from dual union all
 select 2,'0 0 0 00000 00000' from dual union all
 select 3,'00000000'          from dual union all
 select 4,'0a0 0 00000 00000' from dual  
)
 select t.value as "values", 
        regexp_substr(t.value,'[[:space:]]+') as "spaces",
        regexp_substr(t.value,'[0]+') as "zeroes"        
   from t 
  order by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your regex, you've tried using the character class `\s` inside square brackets `[]`. That doesn't work (at least not as expected) - your regex tries to match literal zeroes, backslashes or letters s.

The easiest fix is to get rid of the square brackets and use an or expression with `|`:

```
with v(value) as (
  select '0000 00 00 ' from dual union all
  select '0' || chr(9) || '00000000' from dual union all
  select '000000000' || chr(10) from dual)
select value, 
  regexp_substr(value, '(0|\s)+') as mynum
from v
```

Alternatively, you can use the POSIX character class `[:space:]` inside the square brackets:

```
with v(value) as (
  select '0000 00 00 ' from dual union all
  select '0' || chr(9) || '00000000' from dual union all
  select '000000000' || chr(10) from dual)
select value, 
  regexp_substr(value, '[0[:space:]]+') as mynum2
from v
```